# Can't mock axios instance in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Following [this link](https://binarapps.com/blog/test-ajax-calls-in-react-component-lifecycle), I tried writing a unit test while mocking Axios (using Typescript).

Using an Axios instance to set `baseUrl`.

```
// src/infrastructure/axios-firebase.ts
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosThroughFirebase = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'firebase_URL'
});

export default axiosThroughFirebase;
```

Here's the abridged version of the component I want to test.

```
// src/container/MainContainer/MainContainer.tsx
import axios_firebase from '../../infrastructure/axios-firebase';
...

public componentDidMount() {
    axios_firebase.get('firebase_url/data.json')
       .then(resp => this.setState({ stuff }));
}
```

And then my test file.

```
// src/container/MainContainer/MainContainer.test.tsx
jest.mock('../../infrastructure/axios-firebase', () => {
    return {
       get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(someFakeData))
    };
});

import axios_firebase from '../../infrastructure/axios-firebase';

test('fetches data on componentDidMount', async () => {
    const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<MainContainer />);
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()
       .then(() => {
           expect(axios_firebase.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
});
```

When I run this test, I get the following failure message:

```
● MainContainer › encountered a declaration exception

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

  14 |
  15 |     public componentDidMount() {
> 16 |         axios_firebase.get('url_to_data')
```

I thought I was following the initial link exactly.. I can't imagine that using Typescript is the problem? I can't see why the Axios instance, which was mocked out, would be undefined in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to do with Typescript import/export.

I think you should mock default export. So instead of

```
jest.mock('../../infrastructure/axios-firebase', () => {
    return {
       get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(someFakeData))
    };
});
```

It should be

```
jest.mock('../../infrastructure/axios-firebase', () => {
    return {
       'default' : {
         get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(someFakeData))
       }
    };
});
```

See https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/120#issuecomment-283653644.

Comment: I was able to get past this particular problem using your answer, so I marked it as the answer. Unfortunately, I have immediately run into the following problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/52800158/159446. If you have any thoughts on this, too, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Because in the tutorial in componentDidMount() `axios.get(...).then(...)` is returned.

Comment: Yep, I had to face-palm myself for missing that.