# Can't call .then when mocking axios call inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, axios

I'm trying to unit test `componentDidMount` while mocking an Axios call.

```
// src/App.tsx
import axios_with_baseUrl from './axios-instance-with-baseUrl';
...

public componentDidMount() {
    axios_with_baseUrl.get('/data.json')
       .then(resp => this.setState({ stuff }));
}

// src/App.test.tsx
jest.mock('./axios-instance-with-baseUrl', () => {
    return {
       get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(someFakeData))
    };
});

import axios_with_baseUrl from './axios-instance-with-baseUrl';

test('fetches data on componentDidMount', async () => {
    const app = enzyme.shallow(<App />);
    app.instance().componentDidMount()
       .then(() => {
           expect(axios_with_baseUrl.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
});
```

When I test the above code, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

  26 | test('componentDidMount', async () => {
  27 |   const app = enzyme.shallow(<App />);
> 28 |   app.instance().componentDidMount()
     |   ^
  29 |     .then(() => {
```

I guess it makes sense since `componentDidMount` is a void method, but I'm not sure why tutorials like [this](https://binarapps.com/blog/test-ajax-calls-in-react-component-lifecycle) do it this way. Is it best to simply ignore that pattern?

This is another pattern that I found:

```
await app.instance().componentDidMount();
expect(axios_with_baseUrl.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The bigger question is: are either of the above good patterns for mocking Axios in unit tests? Or should I just rely on something like `axios-mock-adapter`?

Comment: `componentDidMount` is returning undefined - seeing as there's no return in that function, that is the issue

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52767973/3731501 . This is the same problem. You have no promise to chain, so you won't be able to test it efficiently. As for axios-mock-adapter, you can use it for mocking Axios because this is what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return` before `axios_with_base_url` to make `promise`

```
public componentDidMount() {
    return axios_with_baseUrl.get('/data.json')
       .then(resp => this.setState({ stuff }));
}
```